# how do I store function variables outside of the function for use in another file?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am new to coding and want to make a list of the x and y coordinates of where the mouse was clicked to be used in another file.

```
import turtle
import math

t = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()


def rounds(x, y):
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y)) #set x and y coord to mouse
    t.up()
    t.goto(x, y - 8) #move turtle to center of circle
    t.setheading(0) #makes turtle face set direction
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(8)
    t.end_fill()
    return x, y


def getcoord(): #draw function
    turtle.onscreenclick(rounds, 1) #run round every time left click 
    turtle.mainloop() # loops on screen click
```

Comment: Comments in python are introduced via '#', not via '//'

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to coding, an important concept if you want variables from a function outside of the function is that of [scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html), I suggest you read up on it. What you can do is introduce a variable at the 'global' scope that you append to:

```
import turtle
import math

t = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
click_positions = [] # will hold list of (x,y) click positions

def rounds(x, y):
    t.setheading(t.towards(x, y)) #set x and y coord to mouse
    t.up()
    t.goto(x, y - 8) #move turtle to center of circle
    t.setheading(0) #makes turtle face set direction
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(8)
    t.end_fill()
    click_positions.append((x,y)) # build a list of click positions in click_positions

    return x, y


def getcoord(): #draw function
    turtle.onscreenclick(rounds, 1) #run round every time left click 
    turtle.mainloop() # loops on screen click
```

You should store the click positions in a single list rather than two separate lists. In another file, you can then access the data:

```
from your_filename import click_positions
for click in click_positions:
   click_x, click_y = click # unpacks the python tuple (x,y) into two variables such that click_x=x, click_y=y
```